# Function that is in the Schwartz space but is not a bump function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Wikipedia states that the function $f(x)=x^\alpha e^{-a|x|^2}$ for a multi-index $\alpha$ and a positive real number $a$ is in the Schwartz space. I need to find a function that is Schwartz but not a bump function. Could this be a fit? The function is smooth but its support are all real numbers expect $0$ which is not a compact set hence $f$ is not a bump function? Is this true?

Comment: Why not add two bump functions?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you mean?

Comment: What’s your definition of a bump function?

Comment: A smooth function that has compact support.